# ExpressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedError PrimeNG Two Radio Buttons binding to same property

Tags: angular7, primeng

**TLDR**:  Binding two radio buttons to the same underlying property results in invalid behavior and the error "ExpressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedError"

Environment:  Angular 7.3.8, PrimeNg 7.1.3

Example in StackBlitz:
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-primeng-playground-t7nmfx

Ultimately, I understand what's going on here.  The two instances of the radio button are interfering with each other trying to set the initial state and also interfere when setting one or the other.  But I can't see how to get out of this.  Obviously, this is a super simplified example, and the screen layout was provided to me so I can't move the radio outside of the tab.  I really somehow need two of them.  Also I'm not sure if this is related to PrimeNG or not.

Html:

```
<p-tabView>
  <p-tabPanel header="today">
    <div>
      Temperature: {{tempToday}}
    </div>
    <div>
      Show in: 
      <p-radioButton name="groupname" [value]="1" [(ngModel)]="isCelcius"></p-radioButton> C
      <p-radioButton name="groupname" [value]="0" [(ngModel)]="isCelcius"></p-radioButton> F
    </div>
  </p-tabPanel>
  <p-tabPanel header="tomorrow">
    <div>
      Temperature: {{tempTomorrow}}
    </div>
    <div>
      Show in: 
      <p-radioButton name="groupname" [value]="1" [(ngModel)]="isCelcius"></p-radioButton> C
      <p-radioButton name="groupname" [value]="0" [(ngModel)]="isCelcius"></p-radioButton> F
    </div>
  </p-tabPanel>
</p-tabView>
```

Component:

```
  ngOnInit() {
    this.isCelcius = false;
    this.tempToday = 78;
    this.tempTodayInF = 78;
    this.tempTodayInC = 20;
    this.tempTomorrow = 80;
    this.tempTomorrowInF = 80;
    this.tempTomorrowInC = 21;
  }

public get isCelcius(): boolean {
  return this._isCelcius;
}

public set isCelcius(value: boolean ) {
  this._isCelcius = value;
  if(this._isCelcius) {
    this.tempTomorrow = this.tempTomorrowInC;
    this.tempToday = this.tempTomorrowInC;
  } else {
    this.tempTomorrow = this.tempTomorrowInF;
    this.tempToday = this.tempTodayInF;
  }
}

  private _isCelcius: boolean;
  public tempToday: number;
  public tempTomorrow: number;

  private tempTodayInF: number;
  private tempTodayInC: number;
  private tempTomorrowInF: number;
  private tempTomorrowInC: number;
```

Answer (score 2):

I'm going to leave this here in case anyone ever runs into the same problem.

The issue isn't what it appears to be.  What's causing the problem is that the radio button group name is duplicated.  Changing the group name in either of the tabs fixes the issue.

```
      <p-radioButton name="groupname1" [value]="1" [(ngModel)]="isCelcius"></p-radioButton> C
      <p-radioButton name="groupname1" [value]="0" [(ngModel)]="isCelcius"></p-radioButton> F
```